# Очистка памяти от объектов класса в динамической памяти

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток ,
Возник такой вопрос. Допусти у меня есть объект класса. Который в свою очередь имеет просто поля и методы. То есть можно бы было заменить структурой (даже и без методов). Место для него я выделяю в динамической памяти подобно этому

```
 someObj* objPointer = new someObj();
```

То есть этот класс выступает в роли просто контейнера данных и работы с ними.
Вопрос в том, как правильно очистить память от этого класса? Допустим если у меня в есть поле класса указатель на другой класс , то естественно , я пропишу в деструкторе удаление подуровней. 
А как быть с самим классом ? В деструкторе если не брать удаление подуровней, больше писать то и нечего , так как поля класса , не указатели , а статические переменные .
Нужно ли его удалять созданный класс с помощью такой конструкции ?

```
delete objPointer
```

И как правильно вообще работать с объектами классами в динамической памяти, со структурами делал просто через делит , хотя у структуры есть тоже деструктор .
Спасибо заранее ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- При вызове оператора `delete` для указателя на объект класса будет вызван его деструктор.
- В деструкторе вы должны освободить всю память, которую динамически выделили в конструкторе или других методах данного класса.
- Для тех полей класса, которые объявлены в статической памяти, будет вызван соответствующий деструктор автоматически.
- Если класс, к которому относится данный объект, является потомком другого класса, то потом будет вызван деструктор базового класса и его полей (не забывайте, что деструктор должен быть объявлен как виртуальный, иначе будет вызван деструктор только того класса, указателем на который вы пользуетесь. Могут быть утечки памяти и прочие Ужасные Вещи).

И не забывайте, что разница между `struct` и `class` только в том, какие права доступа присваиваются полям данного типа по-умолчанию (`public` для `struct` и `private` для `class`). Больше никаких различий в типах объявления нет!

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите.

Каждый объект является (точнее, может являться) *ответственным* за другие объекты. Часто ответственный объект содержит указатель на объекты, за которые он отвечает. В этом случае разумной политикой будет удалить эти объекты в своём деструкторе.

Таким образом, когда внешний код удалит ответственный объект, при этом вызовется деструктор, и «внутренние» объекты тоже будут удалены.

Более хорошая и современная идея такая: вместо обыкновенного указателя на объект хранить смарт-указатель. Тогда в деструкторе можно не заботиться о подчинённых объектах, они будут удалены автоматически.

Если есть возможность автоматизировать часть логики программы, этим не стоит пренебрегать.

Comment: Спасибо большое , на счет умных укзателях не слышал, почитаю , очень полезно. Просто задание учебное, пока что самому думаю будет полезнее подумать о памяти, чем надеяться на компилятор . А в будущем , если будет потребность, то очень хороший вариант . Спасибо

Comment: Только что попробовал объявил класс(1) в нем поле указатель на другой класс 2. В конструкторах и деструкторах сиаут повпихивал . Создал класс 1 (в котором есть поле указатель на другой класс 2) ,затем удалил его . Вывело только конструктор и деструктор для этого класса 1 . Затем еще выделил память для класса 2 , вывело только конструктор для класса 2 , хотя для класса 1 вызвался деструктор. И только при удалении класса 2 (delet classObj2) вызвался деструктор класса 2 . 
Но насколько я знаю при наследовании конструкторы и деструкторы вызываются и для базовых и для дочерних классов. Стоит ли ?

Comment: Наследование использовать если классы содержат разную по смыслу информацию ? Или же наследовать, но просто для каждого класса запихывать его данные в private и наследовать как public ?

Comment: @Alexandr Crospov: вы путаете два понятия: класс-владелец (тот, который должен удалить другой класс) и класс-предок (в иерархии наследования). Это совсем разные вещи. От предка-класса наследуются его поля и методы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создавать и удалять экземпляр класса так, как написали. Тогда при его удалении c помощью delete работает деструктор класса, написанный Вами или созданный компилятором по умолчанию.
Если Вы создали экземпляр в стеке: someObj obj , то этот же деструктор сработает при выходе из зоны видимиости или в конце программы.